# .NET Core 2.0 HttpClient Singleton throwing 502

Tags: azure, httpclient, microservices

I have a web application acting as a gateway to a variety of internal services. These services are consumed by using a single instance of `HttpClient`, instantiated at startup (i.e. `Startup.cs`)

After a certain period of time, something is causing our `HttpClient` to stop hitting our APIs and immediately fail with HTTP 502 errors for every call using that client. (Note that I can still hit our APIs using other means, such as Postman)

Also be aware that this is all deployed to a variety of AppServices in Azure.

Any ideas as to what could corrupt HttpClient in this manner?

Thanks,
-Tim

Comment: Could you please post the full HTML response you received for 502 errors?

Answer (score 0):

This error is usually given when you are behind a proxy server.
If you are using a proxy you will probably have to authenticate the http client again.
Another possibility is to generate the Singleton instance again when it gives an error, for Example `Singleton.killInstance();` If your implementation is like this:

```
public class Singleton
{
   private static Singleton instance;
   private Singleton() {}
   public static Singleton instance
   {
      get 
      {
         if (instance == null)
         {
            instance = new Singleton();
         }
         return instance;
      }
   }
  public static void Singleton killInstance()
  {
    instance == null
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the error might be, your httpclient request is causing your web server to crash. In order to investigate it, you need to go to to the Event Viewer of your AppService.

Here are the steps to launch the event viewer:

1. Go to Kudu management site of your website (ie https://{sitename}.scm.azurewebsites.net
2. Open menu item: Tools => Support
3. Choose relevant Azure AD Directory of your website
4. Click on **Analyze** => Event Viewer.
5. Check the error messages